# Disable RecyclerView Buttons

Tags: android, recyclerview-layout

`RecyclerView layout`

[image]

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fish, viewGroup,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) viewHolder;
    final DataFish current=data.get(i);

    myHolder.textFishName.setText(current.fishName);
    myHolder.textSize.setText("Size: " + current.sizeName);
    myHolder.textType.setText("Category: " + current.catName);
    myHolder.btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //code here

        }
    } );
```

If `Button` is Clicked in a View all the other Buttons inside its View Should be disabled. This is what my scenario can anyone suggest  How to do that?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have to disable all buttons one by one like this: btn.setClickable(false).

Comment: No, I want to disable buttons According to there position @AgonAvdijaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a public boolean variable in your adapter and set it's default value to false;

`public boolean clicked = false`

inside `onBindViewHolder` check `if (clicked) myHolder.btn.setEnabled(false); else myHolder.btn.setEnabled(true)`

and in your click method set `clicked = true` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

this will disable all buttons,

if you want to disable all other buttons(except this one) use an integer variable insted of boolean `public Integer clickedPosition = null`

and check  `if (clickedPosition != null && clickedPosition != getAdapterPosition) myHolder.btn.setEnabled(false); else myHolder.btn.setEnabled(true);`

and in your click method set `clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
public  Integer clickedPosition;

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fish, viewGroup,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) viewHolder;
    final DataFish current=data.get(i);

    myHolder.textFishName.setText(current.fishName);
    myHolder.textSize.setText("Size: " + current.sizeName);
    myHolder.textType.setText("Category: " + current.catName);
    if(clickedPosition!=null && clickedPosition!=getAdapterPosition()) myHolder.btn.setEnabled(false);
    else myHolder.btn.setEnabled(false);
    myHolder.btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDatasetChanged();
          //code here

        }
    } );

 myHolder.btn1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //code here

            }
        } );
        myHolder.btn2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedPosition = null;
            notifyDatasetChanged();
           //code here

            }
        } );
```

Comment: Can You Make Changes in My given Code Because its kind of bit confusing for me and I want to disable all other button except this one.
As I am New to Coding.
It will great help if you can do this

Comment: thanks a lot it worked.
Now Can you help In One more thing?

Comment: and what is that thing?

Comment: See When I click On that Enter Button after that two more buttons are displayed that are Reached and Logout.
So When I click on Logout  All the buttons which are disabled that should be enabled

Comment: Whenever I click on a Enter Button Another Enter button Expand

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the recyclerview items and disable each button but the clicked one, as follow: (in my case the recycler view is a public static attribute)

```
//exempleActivity.java

public static RecyclerView yourRecyclerView;
...
yourRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.your_recycleriew);
```

.

```
//myRecyclerViewAdapter.java

import yourPackage.yourActivity.yourRecyclerView;
for (int j = 0; j < yourRecyclerView.getChildCount(); j++) {
     YourViewHolder holder = (YourViewHolder) yourRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(j);
     if(i != currentPosition)
          holder.btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: yourRecyclerView as in my file name?

Comment: no, for example, in your activity where you have declared  the recyclerview:
 public static RecyclerView yourRecyclerview;

Comment: But the code which i have pasted is from my adapter And myrecyclerview is in different file

Comment: I have to write this code in BindView Holder or in click method

Comment: I am getting one problem you given code consider only first five position view 
In My case the childcount is 5 and total i have 8 view 
So when i click button on 6 position the app crash

Comment: import yourPackage.yourActivity.yourRecyclerView;                           
yourActivity in your case itsexampleActivity right?

Comment: Still the same thing and because of same reason the app crashes